# C++ sum char and integer

Tags: c++, char, int

I have trouble with solving this. Can you tell me what the result is on the following syntax?

```
strcpy(s,"3x2y1");
s[2]='x'+2; /* what's showing when the following add is done? */
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `s` will be "3xzy1" as `s[2]='x'+2;` makes `s[2]` equal to 'z', where 'z' is a character, not a string.

```
'x'-1=='w';
'x'+1=='y';
'x'+2=='z'
```